# Extracting only my function names from ELF binary

Tags: c, linux, shell, awk, readelf

Im writing a script for extracting all the functions (written by user) in a binary.

The following shell script extracts my function names as well as some library functions which start with `__`.

```
readelf -s ./a.out | gawk '
{ 
  if ($4 == "FUNC" && $3 != "0" && $7 == "13" && $8 != "main") { 
    print "b " $NF; //***Updated
  } 
}' &> function_names;
```

Output of function_names file:

```
b __libc_csu_fini
b PrintDivider    
b PrintFooter    
b __libc_csu_init    
b PrintHeader
```

I would like to extract only my functions. So how to check whether function name starts with `__` or else any other alternatives also highly appreciated.

**Update::**

@djf solution works fine. What if `.c` files which are compiled also may contain a function which starts with `__`? In that case, how to differentiate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about using `readelf` on your object file(s) instead of the linked executable? Then there's no spam from the library functions.
Use the `-c` flag to compile to an object file and not link immediately.

PS: The proper tool to extract names from an executable or object file is `nm`, not `readelf`. Using `nm -P file` has everything you want.

```
$ nm -P tst.o | awk '$2 == "T" {print "b " $1}'
b foo
b main
```

**EDIT**: To ignore `main` and symbols starting with an underscore, use

```
$ nm -P a.out | awk '$2 == "T" && $1 !~ /^_/ && $1 != "main" {print "b " $1}'
```

Comment: nm also gives `_init , _start, _fini`

Comment: @Jeyaram No it doesn't if you use it on the object files instead of the executable. But see my edit.

Comment: `nm -P tst.o | awk '$2 == "T" && $1 != "main" {print "b " $1}'` is exactly wanted.. :)

Answer (score 5):

You could add a [regex](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp.html#Regexp) check to make sure that the function name starts with a letter.

I presume that $8 contains the function name:

```
readelf -s ./a.out | gawk '
{
  if($4 == "FUNC" && $3 != "0" && $7 == "13" && $8 != "main" && $8~/^[[:alpha:]]/) {
    print $NF;
  }
}'
```

Comment: If user defined function also starts with __, then how to differntiate ??? any idea?? pls share.

Comment: @Jeyaram it's really bad practice to name your functions with leading underscores since these names are reserved for the compiler and core libraries... avoid doing that if you can - in C++ its forbidden by the language standard. I'm not sure about C, though. I can't tell you how to differentiate because you haven't told us what your function names look like... C-libraries usually add a prefix to all function names to avoid name clashes with other libraries. Maybe you could filter on such a prefix?

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it through `grep ^[^_]`. [30 char]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can u please explain bit more ??

Comment: @Jeyaram Explain what? You pipe the output through this command and BOOM you get what you want.

Comment: @Jeyaram Now has your question changed? Or what? I don't understand. For me, it's still the same: grep for the names which don't begin by an underscore.

Comment: b is breakpoint command for gdb. so `b <space> <function_name>`. I want to use this file for gdb as input `--command` option.

Comment: @Jeyaram Non sequitur. What is the problem now?

Comment: Any particular reason for the `.*$` part in the regex?

Comment: @Jens Yes, unless I include that, the answer is 28 chars long and SO doesn't let me submit it.

Comment: Ah, then I would have single quoted the regex to avoid the shell from globbing `^[^_]` in case there's a file named `^x` around... :-)